# airflow task is unable to connect to remote oracle database

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, airflow, cx-oracle

airflow task is unable to connect to remote oracle database but i am able to connect to the same remote oracle database using the same code from python shell.
i checked running environment is same for both the shell and airflow.
i am attaching the log error which i am getting.

```
[2018-07-18 13:12:11,037] {models.py:1428} INFO - Executing <Task(AadharNumberValidation): validating_data> on 2018-07-18 07:42:05.573491
[2018-07-18 13:12:11,037] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Running: ['bash', '-c', 'airflow run data_validation validating_data 2018-07-18T07:42:05.573491 --job_id 206 --raw -sd /Users/b0204890/Desktop/python/airflow_home/dags/data_validaton.py']
[2018-07-18 13:12:11,531] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-18 13:12:11,531] {__init__.py:45} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2018-07-18 13:12:11,588] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-18 13:12:11,588] {models.py:189} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/b0204890/Desktop/python/airflow_home/dags/data_validaton.py
[2018-07-18 13:12:11,661] {cli.py:374} INFO - Running on host LTB0204890-Mac.local
[2018-07-18 13:12:11,669] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-18 13:12:11,669] {validation_operators.py:37} INFO - operator_param yadav: Script one validation
[2018-07-18 13:12:11,678] {models.py:1595} ERROR - DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 1): image not found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#macos for help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/b0204890/venv/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1493, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/Users/b0204890/Desktop/python//airflow_home/plugins/validation_operators.py", line 38, in execute
    cursor = create_connection(user="USERNAME",port="PORT",host="HOST",pwd="password",sid="SID")
  File "/Users/b0204890/Desktop/python/airflow_home/utility/validation.py", line 30, in create_connection
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user, pwd, service)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 1): image not found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#macos for help
[2018-07-18 13:12:11,681] {models.py:1616} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY
[2018-07-18 13:12:11,682] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-18 13:12:11,682] {configuration.py:206} WARNING - section/key [smtp/smtp_user] not found in config
[2018-07-18 13:12:11,684] {models.py:1628} ERROR - Failed to send email to: ['tushar.smartcorp@gmail.com']
[2018-07-18 13:12:11,684] {models.py:1629} ERROR - [Errno 61] Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/b0204890/venv/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1493, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/Users/b0204890/Desktop/python//airflow_home/plugins/validation_operators.py", line 38, in execute
    cursor = create_connection(user="USERNAME",port="PORT",host="HOST",pwd="PASSWORD",sid="SID")
  File "/Users/b0204890/Desktop/python/airflow_home/utility/validation.py", line 30, in create_connection
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user, pwd, service)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 1): image not found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#macos for help

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/b0204890/venv/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1618, in handle_failure
    self.email_alert(error, is_retry=True)
  File "/Users/b0204890/venv/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1779, in email_alert
    send_email(task.email, title, body)
  File "/Users/b0204890/venv/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 44, in send_email
    return backend(to, subject, html_content, files=files, dryrun=dryrun, cc=cc, bcc=bcc, mime_subtype=mime_subtype)
  File "/Users/b0204890/venv/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 87, in send_email_smtp
    send_MIME_email(SMTP_MAIL_FROM, recipients, msg, dryrun)
  File "/Users/b0204890/venv/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 107, in send_MIME_email
    s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT) if SMTP_SSL else smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Comment: It is very hard to provide help from this simple stack trace. I'd like to paint a bigger picture. How did you install Oracle client? What have you done so far? Have you visited the link provided in the stack trace? How does your environment look like? What other exception is following but was cut off?

Comment: i had created a virtual environment on mac for python and used pip to installed cx_Oracle pip install cx-Oracle==6.3.1. and also i installed apache-airflow==1.9.0 using pip only.. other error message is added to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Without following all of the instructions the connector will not work. Simply doing an installation for the Python package `cx-Oracle` is not enough. In this case it could also be that the venv of Airflow cannot access all neccessary files or that there is some rights issue.

As stated in the message, you need to follow all steps seen in: https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#macos